# string to key-value conversion in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I like to convert the string values to key value pairs

from this format: `val1-12,val2-32,val3-43`

to `(val1,12),(val2,32),(val3,43)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can combine `flatMap` and `map` like this

```
val string =  Seq("val1-12,val2-32,val3-43")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(string).flatMap(line => line.split(",")).map(row => row.split("-")).map(kv => (kv(0), kv(1)))
```